# Sending and Receiving Emojis in Smack

Tags: android, chat, openfire, smack, emoticons

How can I send and receive Emojis over android application using `smack` library and `OpenFire` sever in Chat Application ?

Comment: emoticons are ASCII chars ... so ... `showAsHtml("it's easy :)".replace(":)", "<img src='smile.png'/>")` should work...

Comment: @kamran, is an emoji different from an emoticon in your case?

Comment: No , I didnt know the difference emoticons and emojis before your comment ,Its emojis not emoticons which I need to add , I am going to edit it .

Answer (score 0):

Well you usually donot send actual images in XMPP communications. The emoji is encoded into a unicode value and then it is decoded at the other end.

Check the emoji unicode chart here:-
http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Last when I used smack I used the below library to encode and decode emojis.
https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon.
This library is very flexible and allows you to add your own emojis as well.

Comment: emoji(Unicode chars) != emoticons(short sequences of ASCII characters) ...

Comment: @Selvin - Emojis center more around ideas rather than the emotions of the person composing the message. The use of emoji's originated in Japan, and the word emoji means "picture character." The range of emoji is broader than emoticons and includes pictures of animals, transportation, business icons, and others. The idea of both being the same, denote an expression through an image.

Comment: *The emoticon is encoded into a unicode value and then it is decoded at the other end.*   ...  emoticon fx `:)` or `:-)` is sendend by plain text (two and three chars in this example) ... it may be replaced with image in client ... but it may be not ... emoji are special unicode chars for some time (2010)

Comment: what you are saying is correct, but is that the intention of the person asking the question? is it that big a deal to send a plain text ":)".

Comment: [emoticon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoticon) vs [emoji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/emoji) ... translation of emoticon to emoji makes no sens as client on the other side may not support unicode ... so it would be better to get `:)` instead some unreadable Unicode char